# How to submit a registration form to a server database using android app?

Tags: android, json

I am developing one android app which uploads the registration filled by user to the sever database when "submit" is clicked.
I am using localhost as server and have placed my php files in my "www" folder of "wamp".

Follow my code below:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mits_form;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.1.145  /android_connect/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " form submitted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // successfully created product
              //  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                //startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen

               // finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," in catch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"finished...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    }
}
```

JSONParser.java

```
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

   }

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

    }
}
```

But when I run the app and click submit then it shows "Unfortunately Application is closed"

This is the error in the logcat:

```
 1449-1449/? E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.mits_form.MainActivity has leaked window     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4288dec8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-  684,192} that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mits_form.MainActivity has leaked window   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4288dec8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:452)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
        at   com.mits_form.MainActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:77)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
        at com.mits_form.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:57)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the createproduct.php file:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

 // array for JSON response
  $response = array();
```

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

// include db connect class
require_once ('dbconnect.php');

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

   // echoing JSON response
   echo json_encode($response);
   }
    ?>
```

please guide.

Comment: You're trying to use `Toast` outside the UI thread.

Comment: what does the php script return ? can you share ? it will help me int testing your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use try catch block in your `onCreate` it will not crash your app, and you'll be able to see the errors via catch block.

Remove `super.onPreExecute();` from `protected void onPreExecute()`. Its causing the leak memory. I have experienced the same.

Do not perform any actions that are related to interface in `protected String doInBackground`, instead use Log.i or other Log methods to print or use debugger.

Use `protected void onPostExecute` to perform any action on user interface, that is the way AsyncTask is designed to work.

Problem was with initializing and configuring, I have moved that part in `onCreate`.
See the code below for details.

```
public class DemoAct extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPrice;
    EditText inputDesc;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.1.102/android/create_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo_act);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        try {
            // Create button
            Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            // button click event
            btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // creating new product in background thread
                    new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("DemoAct", ex.toString());
        }
    }// End onCreate

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                String name = inputName.getText().toString();
                String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
                String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

                // getting JSON Object
                // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_create_product, "POST", params);

                // check log cat fro response
                Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                // check for success tag
                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {

                        // finish();
                    } else {
                        // failed to create product
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " in catch",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("DIG", ex.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "finished...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Comment: i did all the changes u suggested..My application is still crashing when i press the submit button and this is the error in the log cat.

Comment: E/ActivityThread﹕ Activity com.android.launcher2.Launcher has leaked ServiceConnection com.samsung.android.service.gesture.GestureManager$2@437c8270 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.android.launcher2.Launcher has leaked ServiceConnection com.samsung.android.service.gesture.GestureManager$2@437c8270 that was originally bound here
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:979)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:873)

Comment: at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1833)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1821)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:503)
            at com.samsung.android.service.gesture.GestureManager.bindtoService(GestureManager.java:156)
            at com.samsung.android.service.gesture.GestureManager.<init>(GestureManager.java:146)

Comment: also make sure there is no extra spaces in your url

Comment: I have added my php file. Please refer.

Comment: I had used a sample json string, guessing from code.Thanks but no need for php code any more. Have you tested the code I have shared ?

Comment: @  MTahir I am doing it right now..I will tell you if any error is there after testing your code.

Comment: It worked fine when testing on emulator. But when I used my phone and executed the app. it shows finished at the end but the database is not updated.

Comment: Can you please guide how can i update the database in the server using my phone not connected with the same net connection?

Comment: you can ask a new questions and add some details